# Are there any uncountable sets that are computable?

Tags: set-theory, computability

A set $Y\subseteq X$ is computable iff its characteristic function $f_Y:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ defined as
$$f_Y(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & x\in Y \\
0, & x\notin Y
\end{cases}$$
is computable. In principle $Y$ need not be a subset of $\mathbb N$, it may be e.g. a subset of the Baire space $\mathbb N^{\omega}$ (i.e., infinite sequences of natural numbers).

I certainly cannot visualize any uncountable but computable set. Does this have anything to do with ["computably uncountable" sets](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/06/representations-of-uncomputable-and-uncountable-sets/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "computable"?  Usually that is defined only for sets of natural numbers, not for arbitrary sets.

Comment: There are notions of computability that make sense for uncountable sets, sure. See for instance [MR1479636 (99a:68070)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1479636). 
Blum, Lenore; Cucker, Felipe; Shub, Michael; Smale, Steve. **[Complexity and real computation](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0701-6)**. With a foreword by Richard M. Karp. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1998. xvi+453 pp. ISBN: 0-387-98281-7.

Comment: The above is specific to computations on the reals (or $\mathbb R^n$, or $\mathbb C$, and so on). There are also notions for arbitrary sets, in the setting of [higher recursion theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631).

Comment: @EricWofsey I edited the post with a definition.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Does the existence of a computable function with an uncountable set as its domain imply that the characteristic function of that domain is computable? I get the impression that just allowing computation over a set  does not guarantee the computability of that set.

Comment: Will $X =[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, 0\leq x \leq 1\\ 
0, \text{ otherwise }
\end{matrix}\right.$ qualify as an example?

Comment: @rtybase AFAIK the ordering relation over the reals is not computable.

Comment: I can definitely write a computer program with that function. And for some reals we can definitely generate decimals with any precision, but we only need $10^{-1}$ precision. Problem is, not every real is computable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant ... but I don't think it's a problem of the $f(x)$ defined above.

Comment: @rtybase While such program may be written, there is no guarantee that it will ever halt. Since there are uncountably many uncomputable reals, I would hazard a guess that at least an uncountable number of them resides within the bounds of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Presumably, the second $X$'s on the first line of your question refers to a different $X$ than first $X$ and the two $X$'s in your formula for $f$. Otherwise, your $f$ is just identically $1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right, thanks for pointing it out - edited the post.

Comment: @DawidK but $f$ doesn't care about the size of the set, $f$ only cares about its input $x \in X$ (or the structure of the input). Like the set of even natural numbers $\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $f(m)$ in this case is $ m \text{ & } 1 == 0 $ (binary AND)

Comment: @rtybase Yes, the size in principle does not matter. I was just saying that we may theoretically stumble upon an $x$ that cannot be even approximated with arbitrary precision (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0480.pdf). E.g. it may have only $0$s ($0.00000...$) preceding a positive digit, and there may be no computable function that allows us to approximate this $x$ closely enough to reach this digit.

Comment: Well, for the purpose of $f(x)$ defined above and (e.g.) $x=0.00000...$ we only need one decimal after ".", i.e. $x=0.00000... \rightarrow x'=0.0$ and comparing $0 \leq x' \leq 1$ is the same as comparing $0 \leq x \leq 1$. This trick will not be able to answer the question if $x=0$ or $x=1$, but $f$ doesn't care about that either. And while I was typing I figured out that $1.000...$ is indeed a problem :)

Comment: @rtybase You are right, I should have said $x=1.0000...$ and then a nonzero digit. If we cannot compute whether $x$ has only $0$s after the comma, we cannot decide $x\geq 1$. EDIT: And after I finished typing I saw your edit :)